# Differential and Common Mode Signals

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, differential, common-mode

if  ı have  amplifier and my ınput ac voltage and v is 2v haw can ı Guess and sketch output of common mode signal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I have no idea what you're asking.